# How to count no of files in given directory in C# Console Application

Tags: c#

I am trying to implement to count no of file in given directory

I have to input directory path in command line it has to be give no of files in that directory

I find source code for hardcoded path following is the code

```
var info = new DirectoryInfo("D:\\");
var files = info.GetFiles();
var dirs = info.GetDirectories();
files.Length;
dirs.Length;
```

Any help Appreciated

Comment: What's wrong with the code posted? I don't see any though?

Comment: `Console.WriteLine("Enter a directory path");` `var path = Console.ReadLine();` `var info = new DirectoryInfo(path);` then the rest of your code. Of course, some checks about the input given would be necessary.

Answer (score 1):

The following is a very simple solution to either read the path from the input or supply it via a command line parameter:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var path = args.Length > 0 ? args[0] : Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("File in folder: {0}", 
        Directory.GetFiles(path).Length));
}
```

- `args` contains the command line parameters
- [`Console.ReadLine()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readline%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) reads the input from the console until `Enter` is pressed

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Directory.GetFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3hwtke0f.aspx) to get files inside Directory and ReadLine to get the Directory as Input

```
 Console.WriteLine("Enter your directory");
 var directory= Console.ReadLine();
 int fileCount = Directory.GetFiles(directory).Length;
 Console.WriteLine("Number of files",fileCount);
```

Comment: i want to input path ..in u r code path is hard coded

Comment: @user3378112 You have posted your question like that, check now